# How can I modify jira hash ticket id linked to my Commit after commit?

Tags: git, jira, issue-tracking

I made a commit with Jira link issue but I made a mistake in the id of an issue so I wanna change it to the correct Jira link issue.
any help

**Update:**

The propose of that question is to change the last commit message so to achieve that uses "git commit --amend" you can change the id of the issue or the entire message.

*sorry for misleading question*

Comment: Search for undo last commit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git)

Comment: the answer uses "git commit --amend" to edit the last commit message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ git reset --soft HEAD~1         # undo last commit
# fix the link here

$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Fix jira link'      
$ git push -f origin HEAD         # (-f) force push, replace the remote history by local
```